# Async method does not return asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I'm having a problem with an async method that I implemented. The method basically makes a HttpRequest to a resource and deserializes the string if the request is successful. I wrote a test for the method, and it works. But the method does never return when I call it from a controller?

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> Get()
    {
        try
        {
            var resourceSegmentUri = new Uri(_uri, UriKind.Relative);

            var response = await _client.GetAsync(resourceSegmentUri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var submission = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<T>>(submission);
            }

            if (response.Content != null)
            {
                var message = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                throw new WebException(message.Result, (WebExceptionStatus)response.StatusCode);
            }

        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Logger.Error("GET Request failed with status: {0}", e.Status);
            throw;
        }

        throw new Exception();
    }
```

Code that never returns:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var api = new Api();
   var test = api.Get().Result; //Never returns
   return View();
}
```

Test that works:

```
[Test]
public void GetShouldReturnIfSuccessfulRequest()
{
    var api = new Api();
    var submission = api.Get();

    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(submission));
    Assert.NotNull(submission);
}
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. There is no `return ...;` statement in your `Index()` method, therefore it can't return anything.

Comment: Sorry missed the return statement, but it's inrelevant really.

Comment: Change your test so that is gets the result of the async method otherwise you're not testing what you intended. `api.Get()` should probably be `api.Get().Result`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've got a deadlock because you're calling `.Result` in your controller action.

If you use `async/await` then you have to use asynchronous actions too.

So something like this should fix it:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  var api = new Api();
  var test = await api.Get(); // Should return
}
```

There's a comprehensive article about this here: [*Using Asynchronous Methods in ASP.NET MVC 4*](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4)

Comment: Does not work. I have tried it. Basically in my real solution I wrap the Get() method in a service method that returns a model to the controller.

Comment: @BjBlazkowicz Then the best option would be to make the service method `async` too. If you start using `async/await` you have to use it all the way up the call stack.

Comment: I have made the service method async, still does not work. The thing is that I wrote a test for it in NUnit and it works fine. But the method never returns when calling it from a controller.

Comment: @BjBlazkowicz Just saw your edit - in your test, `submission` will be the `Task` not the result, so it's not really testing your method.

Comment: +1. @BjBlazkowicz: I explain the cause of the deadlock [on my blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) and in my [recent MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Hmm. Like you said, the method returns if I make the Action async. But does this imply that I have to have async Task<T> methods in the whole call chain?

Comment: @BjBlazkowicz Yes - that's right. Stephen's blog explains this well.

Comment: This is exactly the issue I was having! Thank you!